# Filter Column but it not come back

Tags: angular, typescript

I will make a filter to filter unwanted columns from the display. But when I press open again, that column disappears and doesn't show up. I have to do something more. It's been 3 days since I learned angular.

onAllCheckBox(checkButton: any) {

```
const isStatusChecked = checkButton.STATUS;

this.tableTotalDisplay1 = this.tableTotalDisplay1.filter(t => {
  return !(t.COL_NAME === checkButton.NAME) || isStatusChecked;
});

console.log('---', this.tableTotalDisplay1);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you can maintain a separate array that holds the columns to display (visible columns), when a checkbox is checked, you add the column to the `visibleColumns` array, and when it is unchecked, you remove it from the array. Then, you can use the `visibleColumns` array to render the table.

```
// Define an array to hold the names of the visible columns
visibleColumns: string[] = [];

onAllCheckBox(checkButton: any) {
  const columnName = checkButton.NAME;
  const isStatusChecked = checkButton.STATUS;

  if (isStatusChecked) {
    // Checkbox is checked, show the column
    if (!this.visibleColumns.includes(columnName)) {
      this.visibleColumns.push(columnName);
    }
  } else {
    // Checkbox is not checked, hide the column
    this.visibleColumns = this.visibleColumns.filter(name => name !== columnName);
  }

  console.log('Visible Columns:', this.visibleColumns);
}
```

Now, you can use the `visibleColumns` array to filter the `tableTotalDisplay1` array and render only the visible columns in your table. If you have a list of all possible columns, you can filter them like this:

```
// Filter out only the columns whose names are in the 'visibleColumns' array
this.tableTotalDisplay1 = allColumns.filter(col => this.visibleColumns.includes(col.NAME));
```

Comment: My problem is that when I close a column it closes as selected but when I open the column it doesn't show back. thanks for help

Comment: I edited my answer to the best of ability. I hope someone will help you if it's not give your desired output